# OS X Force WiFi to connect specific SSID/2.4GHz or 5GHz?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

The problem is that OS X sometimes being stupid and keep connect to a AP with bad signal. For example, I have 5 router with same SSID, and it kept connect the one with the worst signal.Another example is that I have 2.4G and 5G network with same SSID, and sometime it will jump from those networks.
I wonder if there is a method to force the OS X (Specifically 10.10 aka Yosemite) to connect to the router I wanted, and force it to stay 2.4G or 5G as I want?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [-MacOSX- How to connect to specify bssid from terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762919/macosx-how-to-connect-to-specify-bssid-from-terminal)